# How to update just altered global temporary table in procedure? pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

have to alter table and update the values in altered temporary table. Is it possible to solve this problem or should I fulfill temporary table using loop instead of `INSERT INTO ttb_customers SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;`?

But the problem is I need a procedure to run in a job. I have two tables, they are similar and on of them is expanded. I need to migrate data from one table to another expanded table and fulfill with values depending on other values.

Here I made the little example how it looks like.

```
  -- create trmporaty table
    CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ttb_customers
    ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
    AS SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 1=0;



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_MISSING_ROWS IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ttb_customers ADD(
        email users.email%type,
        ubi number(20)
    ) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE migrate_customers IS
    email_ USERS.EMAIL%type;
    ubi_ number(20) := 0;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ttb_customers SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;

    ADD_MISSING_ROWS;

    FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM ttb_customers) LOOP
        IF i.SALARY > 500 THEN
            email_ := CONCAT(i.NAME, '@lux.com');
            ubi_ := 0;
        ELSE
            email_ := CONCAT(i.NAME, '@basic.com');
            ubi_ := 100;
        END IF;

        -- this part does not work
        UPDATE ttb_customers SET email=email_, ubi=ubi_ WHERE ID=i.ID;
    
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: As your GTT is on commit delete rows, when you call add_missing_rows which executes a DDL with an explicit commit, the rows will be deleted. You want to put the data in a GTT and then add columns, or you want to add the column to the original table?

Comment: Now I see one of the problems, thanks a lot. I need have two tables and I'm going to migrate data from one table to another. I need to change GTT and add some missing columns and fulfill them with data. after that I will use `INSERT INTO MY_END_TABLE SELECT * FROM GTT_TABLE`

Comment: To migrate data from A-table to B-table (they are similar. but B has more columns that I need to fulfill with values) I think I should create two temporary tables - A-GTT and B-GTT. Insert data from A-table to A-GTT, make another procedure to insert data from A-GTT to B-GTT. add data I need. And use `INSERT INTO B-Table SELECT * FROM B-GTT`

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with out a procedure

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ttb_customers (email varchar2(100), name varchar2(100), ubi int, salary int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ttb_customers VALUES('test@test.com','tom', -1, 499)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ttb_customers VALUES('test@test.com','James', -1, 591)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE ttb_customers SET email=
> CASE WHEN SALARY > 500  THEN CONCAT(NAME, '@lux.com')
> ELSE CONCAT(NAME, '@basic.com') END 
> , ubi= CASE WHEN SALARY > 500  THEN 0 ELSE 100 END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ttb_customers
> ```
>
> ```
> EMAIL         | NAME  | UBI | SALARY
> :------------ | :---- | --: | -----:
> tom@basic.com | tom   | 100 |    499
> James@lux.com | James |   0 |    591
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39c1e3976e122dc88449752b33c6888d)*

Answer (score 0):

And why not do it all in just one SQL, like this where END_TABLE is your 'normal' final table, not a GTT:

```
Insert into end_table (....,email,ubi)
select t.*,
CASE WHEN SALARY > 500  THEN CONCAT(NAME, '@lux.com')
ELSE CONCAT(NAME, '@basic.com') END ,
 CASE WHEN SALARY > 500  THEN 0 ELSE 100 END 
from ttb_customers;
```

Do you really need a GTT?

Comment: I have to do a lot of manipulations with data in GTT before I insert the data to another database. It is just a little example what I gonna do